# Виртуальные методы, наследование и контейнеры STL

Tags: c++, list, наследование

Хотел получить контейнер, который хранит как экземпляры класса-родителя, так и наследника. Но его методы должны быть разными.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
class Entity
{public:
    std::string name = "Entity";
    virtual void update()
    {
        std::cout << "Metod Entity" << '\n';
    }
};

class MovingPlatform:public Entity
{
public:
    void update()
    {
        std::cout << "Metod MovingPlatform"<<'\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::list <Entity> layers;
    Entity a;
    MovingPlatform b; b.name = "MovingPlatform";
    layers.emplace_back(a); layers.emplace_back(b);

    for (auto it = layers.begin(); it != layers.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->name << ": "; it->update();
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Однако, вызывается метод класса-родителя.

```
Entity: Metod Entity
MovingPlatform: Metod Entity
```

Хотелось бы достучаться до метода класса-наследника. При этом просто итерируясь по контейнеру.

Comment: Храните в списке указатели на `Entity`. Для ссылок тоже работать должно, но я не помню можно ли в список положить ссылки. Документацию на std::list надо почитать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот смотрите - в объявлении `std::list<Entity>` вы говорите четко и однозначно, что будете хранить объекты `Entity` - под них выделяется соответствующее место, выполняется разрешение вызовов при компиляции и т.д.

Когда вы пытаетесь туда воткнуть  объект потомка, вы получаете *срезку*. Чтобы добиться того, что вы хотите - вам нужно хранить не сами объекты, а указатели на них (обычные или интеллектуальные - что вам больше подходит).

Можно бы хранить ссылки, но *ссылки как таковые не хранятся* - так что их надо заворачивать в другие классы; думаю, однако, что сейчас эта тема немного выходит за рамки ваших знаний, но если интересно - то обратите внимание на https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref.

Вот пример с применением `unique_ptr`:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void doit() { cout << "Base!\n"; }
    virtual ~Base() { cout << "deleted...\n"; }
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    void doit() override { cout << "Derived!\n"; }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Base>> v;
    v.emplace_back(new Base);
    v.emplace_back(new Derived);
    v.emplace_back(new Base);
    v.emplace_back(new Derived);
    v.emplace_back(new Base);

    for(auto& o: v) o->doit();

    for(auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) (*i)->doit();

}
```

Comment: А можно пример работы с хранением указателей и доступа к полям объекта в контейнере STL? Тема очень интересная. Я как-то пробовал, но у меня не получилось создать вектор из указателей и потом по ним обращаться к объектам.

Comment: См. дополнение к ответу.

Comment: for(auto& o: v) o->doit(); Можно пример для цикла с итератором, а то мне нужно удалять из коллекции и сам итератор является указателем. В данном случае, если пробегаться итератором, то получается указатель на указатель и тут я теряюсь совсем.

Comment: Дописал еще одну строчку :)

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, надо же разименовать указатель...

Comment: Извиняюсь за оффтоп, но почему нельзя хранить ссылки на объекты в коллекциях ? Ссылка же, по своей сути, является указателем, который неявно разименовывается компилятором?

Comment: @Ladence По сути - где-то глубоко внутри - да, но по факту ссылка не может быть изменена или присвоена - будет изменяться или присваиваться сама переменная.